# Bootstrap form-inline controls overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an inline form with Bootstrap 3 and I can't figure out how to keep the inputs from overlapping.  I hope you can see from the screenshot that the third input is overlapping the second and the fourth in overlapping it. How can I get them to align next to each other?

[image]

Here are the main parts of the html;

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control addon-input" id="units" name="units" placeholder="units" value="30" type="text">
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="string optional form-control addon-input" id="unit_price" name="unit_price" placeholder="unit price" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It "works" for me. Maybe the problem is with other CSS or with the container? http://jsfiddle.net/h88fu/1/

Comment: Please check the 'margin-left' css property of input here, it may cause this issue.

Comment: estebarb Thats weird, when I first looked at your fiddle a few hours ago, it was inline as expected, now it's vertical.  Did you change anything?